# Why won't my raspberry pi 2 model B open any files or display the taskbar?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, openbox

A friend and I are trying to set up a new raspberry pi 2 model B that runs Raspbian Wheezy. We can boot into open box, but we cannot do anything more than see that GUI and right click. When trying to open the waste basket or other files, the screen just flashes. The task bar won't appear also, and we can't open a terminal.

We have tried to change the `gpu_mem` in the `/boot/config.txt` file, thinking that the Raspberry pi didn't have the necessary memory to support these components. It did not work. We adjusted the overscan too, to make sure these items weren't appearing outside of the screen, but this wasn't the problem either.

Any ideas?

Comment: So, it doesn't open *specific* files, or does it refuse to open **any** file?

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy it won't open any file